# XPATH query using python

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

I have an html file resulting from an `ifort` code coverage report. This html file contains numerous lines as follows:

```
<a name="l1" style="background-color: #ffffff">      module WriteOutput</a>
```

I succeeded in importing the file using the following in python:

```
from lxml import html
with open(SampleSourceFile, "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)
```

Then I was actually able to get all the `name` attributes using the following XPATH syntax

```
tree.xpath(r'/html/body//a/@name')
```

I see that this offers interesting possibilities. Is it also possible to extract the content of the `<a>` tag? Namely in this case the string 'module WriteOutput' using XPATH?

Also can I add some constraints? for instance I'd like to only get back the `names` of the `<a>` tags with a certain `background-color`. Are these things possible?

Thanks,

Comment: You can try `//a[@style="background-color: #ffffff"]/@name | //a[@name and @style="background-color: #ffffff"]/text()` to get both text content and `name` attribute values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have not tried it , but something like this should work
tree.xpath(r'/html/body/a[@background-color eq "#ffffff"]')